# OpenCV: "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:" while attempting to compile

Tags: c, opencv

Environment:
OS: macOS,
OpenCV: 2.4.12

I just started learning OpenCV, and I wrote down a code from a book, which is,

```
#include <opencv/highgui.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
        int iscolor = -1;
        IplImage* img = cvLoadImage(argv[1], iscolor);
        cvNamedWindow("Example1", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
        cvShowImage("Example1", img);
        cvWaitKey(0);

        cvReleaseImage(&img);
        cvDestroyWindow("Example1");
        return 0;
}
```

When I tried to compile this code with this command - `gcc opencv1.c -o opencv1`, it showed an error with the following message.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_cvDestroyWindow", referenced from:
      _main in opencv1-78cabd.o
  "_cvLoadImage", referenced from:
      _main in opencv1-78cabd.o
  "_cvNamedWindow", referenced from:
      _main in opencv1-78cabd.o
  "_cvReleaseImage", referenced from:
      _main in opencv1-78cabd.o
  "_cvShowImage", referenced from:
      _main in opencv1-78cabd.o
  "_cvWaitKey", referenced from:
      _main in opencv1-78cabd.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Does anybody know the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the `OpenCV` libraries when compiling, `pkg-config` can help:

```
gcc `pkg-config --cflags opencv` `pkg-config --libs opencv` opencv1.c -o opencv1
```

Comment: I just re-compiled and got the another message. `ld: library not found for -lippicv`.

Comment: Try adding the compiler option: `-DINSTALL_CREATE_DISTRIB=ON` at the very end, take a look to https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/5852